# Unit Testing a Windows MFC (CTreeCtrl in special)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mfc

I have to write some unit tests for a class that contains a CTreeCtrl object. Problem is i cannot pass the whole chain of windows and init the application as usual, so when using this object i get an error on calling Create or Adding item. For example, i know i cannot pass null on Create as the pParentWnd, but in my case this would be the case. Is there a way to create a "mocked" CWnd object to pass?
I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Google Test/Mock
How can i initialize a CTreeCtrl outside of a normal WinApi Window?

Comment: Is it tree control specific functionality you want to test? Can't you just not initialize your CTreeCtrl when no parent is passed in, update the class so that it can deal with that, and then have your test test the rest of the functionality? Is your class to be tested a CDialog derived class? As to your actual question: yes you can create an empty window and then use that as the parent for any UI related controls. But from the limited information we have, it seems to me you'll have to refactor to make your class testable.

Comment: @Roel yes, functionality depends on the treectrl and the items in it. Class to be tested is derived from CWnd. How can i create an empty window?

Comment: Just call ::CreateWindow() or CWnd::Create() to create a window. But it's difficult to put this in regular unit tests, as you'd need a top-level window (a dialog or a regular window) to be used as a parent for any child windows you want to test. But then the problem becomes that your application loops in its message pump so you'd have to write your tests in the message loop somewhere, but then that usually doesn't work together very will with unit test frameworks. The usual way to solve this is to factor the non-ui functionality out into a separate class.

Comment: And then you'd use a mock for the UI parts. But it's always finicky. And especially hard when you have to go back and add tests to a closely coupled control that was written without testability in mind. From what I understand of your question, there is no easy way to do what you want - you can't just sprinkle in some testing. Either way, to create an empty window, look up any barebones win32 tutorial, they always start with 'my first window' or something like that. That's an empty window. But, again, you'll be stuck with the message loop so I don't think this is really what you want.